# Make a list with mongodb and python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I'm working with mongodb and python. So I have a huge JSON that is within the database in mongodb, and I wanted to make a list where he gave a "print" on the screen of the things I looked for.

```
db.getCollection('request').aggregate(
    {$match : {"kind" :"qpxExpress#tripsSearch"}},
    {$unwind:"$trips.tripOption"},
    {$project: {"trips.tripOption.saleTotal":1}}
)
```

I use it to look inside the JSON, but I wanted one of the print on the screen with a code in python.

Here is a JSON exempo that I get the information:

> http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb959272

I've tried to do something but doesn't work:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
cursor = db.getCollection('request').aggregate(
    {$match : {"kind" :"qpxExpress#tripsSearch"}},
    {$unwind:"$trips.tripOption"},
    {$project:{"trips.tripOption.saleTotal":1}}
)

for saleTotal in cursor:    
    print(saleTotal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (assuming your DB name is `test`):

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.test
cursor = db.request.aggregate(
    [
        {$match : {"kind" :"qpxExpress#tripsSearch"}},
        {$unwind:"$trips.tripOption"},
        {$project:{"trips.tripOption.saleTotal":1}}
    ]
)
for saleTotal in cursor:    
    print(saleTotal)
```